# Use IServiceCollection extensions with DryIoc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dryioc

There are many extensions for the `IServiceCollection` - in my case I use `AddHttpClient`.

My scenario is that I register general stuff in the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup.cs` where `IServiceCollection` is used to register services. Everything that is needed only in specific projects is registered in an extension method in the respective project, but there the DryIoc `IContainer` is used due to how the DryIoc container must be integrated in an ASP .NET Core project.

Now I have a HttpClient that I only need in a specific project. Therefore I would like to put the registration for it in the respective project. Problem is I want to use AddHttpClient for it which I normally can only use with IServiceCollection.

My question: Is there any way to use it in my other project. Maybe by getting it from the DryIoc container or something else.

This is the general structure of the described files:

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.RegisterSomeService();
        // register other stuff
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new DryIocServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureContainer<Container>(SomeProject.ContainerSetup.Initialize);
}
```

**ContainerSetup.cs** in SomeProject

```
public static class ContainerSetup
{
    public static void Initialize(HostBuilderContext hostContext, IContainer container)
    {
        container.Register<SomeService>();
        // register other stuff
        // here I want to use AddHttpClient
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the `IContainer` extension `Populate` which is part of [DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection).

With it I edited my ContainerSetup.cs as follows

```
public static class ContainerSetup
{
    public static void Initialize(HostBuilderContext hostContext, IContainer container)
    {        
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        
        services.AddHttpClient<MyTypedClient>()
            .Configure[...];
        
        container.Populate(services); // with this call all services registered above will be registered in the container
        
        // register other stuff if necessary
        container.Register<SomeService>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to look inside the AddHttpClient https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,72bc67c4aadb77fc

and maybe make the same registrations with `IContainer` instead of the service collection.

### Update:

Another idea is to register `IServiceCollection` into itself (or maybe it is already automatically registered?), then resolve it from IContainer and AddHttpClient..

Comment: Yeah, that were exactly my two ideas. First one is possible but pretty ugly because there are sooooo many registration within `AddHttpClient`.
The Second approach I also checked. By default it is not registered, but it would be possible I think. Only thing I don't know if it would have any bad side effects. Will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Nope, does not seem to work. The registrations are only done in the instance of the `IServiceCollection` that is resolved. After this, they are not part of the DryIoC container. Or maybe I do it wrong.